# Scala int value of String characters

Tags: string, scala, char, int

I just want to sum the digits of a BigInt. I can do

```
scala> "1 2 3".split(" ").map(_.toInt).sum
res23: Int = 6
```

So I tried

```
scala> BigInt(123).toString().map(_.toInt).sum
res24: Int = 150
```

This doesn't work because it maps the characters to their Unicode values.

Both the following work, but is there a more elegant way than using the Java static method or an extra toString conversion?

```
BigInt(123).toString().map(Character.getNumericValue(_)).sum
BigInt(123).toString().map(_.toString.toInt).sum
```

(I've also done it using a recursive function, sidestepping strings altogether, but I'm interested here in a concise 1-liner.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow... these answers are all over the place! Here, do this:

```
BigInt(123).toString().map(_.asDigit).sum
```

Comment: Nice to see another way. It's the same in terms of performance and conciseness as `BigInt(123).toString().map(_.getNumericValue).sum` (well, the name is a bit shorter), and seems to do the same thing.

Comment: @Luigi The fastest way is probably `map(_ - '0')`.

Answer (score 6):

How about not using Strings at all?

```
def sumDigits(b:BigInt):BigInt = {
  if (b < 10) b else b%10 + sumDigits(b/10)
}
```

Comment: +1:  Definitely preferable in real world, though it may be the "recursive function, sidestepping strings altogether" mentioned in the question.

Comment: the OP also says he is interested in a "concise 1-liner", indicating that his "recursive function, sidestepping strings altogether" wasn't as concise.

Comment: Thanks, yep I'd got something similar already, but nice to know that this is the real-world way to go!

Comment: This, it turns out, is a _horrible_ answer in disguise!  (I initially though it looked good.)  It is not tail recursive and uses `O(N^2)` memory where `N` is the number of binary digits!  If you avoid this horrible fate by making it tail recursive, it _still_ takes an order of magnitude longer than `.toString`.

Comment: @Rex Kerr:  Interesting point, and you're right...  I guess I shouldn't prefer this in the real world as previously noted!  I'll leave my upvote though.

Comment: FWIW my version was tail recursive: `def sumDig(b: BigInt, sum: Int):Int = {
    if (b == 0) sum
    else sumDig(b / 10, sum + (b % 10).toInt)
  }`

Comment: @Rex: Where in the question does it say the answer should perform well? If it's really needed, one can easily make it tail recursive.

Comment: @Kim - it doesn't say that, but it doesn't perform well when tail recursive either.

Answer (score 3):

This is not short, and certainly not efficient, but it is another way to go:

```
scala> Iterator.iterate(BigInt(123))(_/10).takeWhile(_>0).map(_%10).sum
res1: scala.math.BigInt = 6
```

(and you probably want an `Int`, which is faster anyway but requires `.map(i=>(i%10).toInt)`.)

The problem with this method (and straightforward recursion) is that you have to compute as many divisions as digits.  (You could use `/%` to speed things up by a factor of 2, but that's still a problem.)  Converting to a string is much faster because all those explicit `BigInt` creations can be avoided.

If you actually want something that works *fast* (not what you asked for, I know), you need a divide-and-conquer approach:

```
def fastDigitSum(b: BigInt): Int = {
  val bits = b.bitLength
  if (bits < 63) math.abs(b.toLong).toString.map(_-'0').sum
  else {
    val many = 256
    val zeros = math.ceil(bits*0.150515).toInt // constant is 0.5*log(2)/log(10)
    val root = (
      if (zeros<many) BigInt("1" + "0"*zeros)
      else {
        Iterator.iterate((BigInt("1"+"0"*many),many))(x => (x._1 * x._1, 2*x._2)).
          find(_._2 > zeros/2).get._1
      }
    )
    val (q,r) = b /% root
    fastDigitSum(q) + fastDigitSum(r)
  }
}
```

---

Edit: If you want *really* fast conversions at all sizes, I've modified my scheme as follows.  There are some not-entirely-functional bits due largely to a lack of a `takeTo` method.  This should be faster than everything else at all sizes (though it asymptotes to `fastDigitSum` performance for very large BigInts).

Probably will run better on 64 bit machines than 32.

No strings were harmed in the making of this function.

```
object DigitSum {
  val memend = BigInt(10000000000000000L) :: BigInt(100000000) :: Nil

  def longSum(l: Long, sum: Int = 0): Int = {
    if (l==0) sum else longSum(l/10, sum + (l%10).toInt)
  }

  def bigSum(b: BigInt, memo: List[BigInt] = Nil): Int = {
    val bits = b.bitLength
    if (bits < 64) longSum(b.toLong)
    else {
      val mem = (
        if (memo.isEmpty) {
          val it = Iterator.iterate(memend.head)(x=>x*x).drop(1)
          var xs = memend
          while (xs.head.bitLength*4 <= bits) xs = it.next :: xs
          xs
        }
        else memo.dropWhile(_.bitLength > bits/2)
      )
      val (q,r) = b /% mem.head
      bigSum(q,memo) + bigSum(r,memo)
    }
  }
}
```

(Okay--this is ending up sort of like code golf at this point.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's much better than the ones you've already got, but

```
BigInt(123).toString().split("").tail.map(_.toInt).sum
```

also works.

Also

```
BigInt(123).toString().map(_.toInt - '0'.toInt).sum
```

and per Rex Kerr's comment, this can be simplified to

```
BigInt(123).toString().map(_-'0').sum
```

Comment: You've got it--the `.toInt`s are unnecessary since all math converts to integers.  You just need `map(_ - '0')`!

Answer (score 2):

This in not an answer to the question but a speed test of the suggestions. I ran the tests several times to ensure the VM was warmed up and results were consistent: these results are representative and are for 10000 iterations. See code for definitions of what these methods are.

For 10-digit BigInts

```
fastDigitSum: 0.020618047 seconds
stringSum:    0.023708908 seconds
stringSum2:   0.02940999 seconds
stringSum3:   0.021641507 seconds
division:     0.052856631 seconds
```

For 50-digit BigInts

```
fastDigitSum: 0.183630732 seconds
stringSum:    0.110235062 seconds
stringSum2:   0.134900857 seconds
stringSum3:   0.096670394 seconds
division:     0.317359989 seconds
```

For 100-digit BigInts

```
fastDigitSum: 0.427543476 seconds
stringSum:    0.228062302 seconds
stringSum2:   0.277711389 seconds
stringSum3:   0.20127497 seconds
division:     0.811950252 seconds
```

For 100,000-digit BigInts (1 iteration)

```
fastDigitSum: 0.581872856 seconds
stringSum:    2.642719635 seconds
stringSum2:   2.629824347 seconds
stringSum3:   2.61327453 seconds
division:     30.089482042 seconds
```

So it seems `BigInt(123).toString().map(_-'0').sum` is the winner for speed and conciseness for smaller BigInts, but Rex Kerr's method is good if your BigInts are huge.

Benchmark code:

```
object Benchmark extends App{
  def fastDigitSum(b: BigInt): Int = {
    val bits = b.bitLength
    if (bits < 63) math.abs(b.toLong).toString.map(_-'0').sum
    else {
      val many = 256
      val zeros = math.ceil(bits*0.150515).toInt // constant is 0.5*log(2)/log(10)
      val root = (
        if (zeros<many) BigInt("1" + "0"*zeros)
        else {
          Iterator.iterate((BigInt("1"+"0"*many),many))(x => (x._1 * x._1, 2*x._2)).
            find(_._2 > zeros/2).get._1
        }
      )
      val (q,r) = b /% root
      fastDigitSum(q) + fastDigitSum(r)
    }
  }

  def stringSum(b: BigInt) = b.toString.map(_.getNumericValue).sum
  def stringSum2(b: BigInt) = b.toString.map(_.toString.toInt).sum
  def stringSum3(b: BigInt) = b.toString.map(_ - '0').sum

  def division(b: BigInt) = sumDig(b, 0)
  def sumDig(b: BigInt, sum: Int):Int = {
    if (b == 0) sum
    else sumDig(b / 10, sum + (b % 10).toInt)
  }

  def testMethod(f: BigInt => Int):Double = {
    val b = BigInt("12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890")
    val b2 = BigInt("1234567890")
    val b3 = BigInt("1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890")
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    var i = 0
    while(i < 10000){
      f(b3)
      i += 1
    }
    (System.nanoTime().toDouble - t0)/1e9
  }

  def runTest(){
    var i = 0
    while (i < 5) {
      println("fastDigitSum: " + testMethod ({fastDigitSum}) + " seconds")
      println("stringSum:    " + testMethod ({stringSum}) + " seconds")
      println("stringSum2:   " + testMethod ({stringSum2}) + " seconds")
      println("stringSum3:   " + testMethod ({stringSum3}) + " seconds")
      println("division:     " + testMethod ({division}) + " seconds")
      i += 1
    }
  }

  runTest()
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try a BigInt with 100,000 digits?  (Just one run is enough to time, you don't need to do it 10k times.)

Comment: @Rex - indeed, then your method wins. I have updated the results.

Comment: My method wins for more sizes on my machine, but anyway, I've updated it so it should win everywhere all the time :)

Comment: @Rex yep, your new version is 2-3 times faster than anything else, definitely the way to go if speed is the prime consideration. Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that the RichChar class has a getNumericValue method, so the answer would be

```
BigInt(123).toString().map(_.getNumericValue).sum
```

Comment: This is actually _longer_ than `.toString.toInt`.  This doesn't sound like a very good answer unless you wanted something that you didn't specify.  Roby's got the shortest answer (with my suggestion).

Comment: @Rex I'm not too worried about how many letters there are in a method name - for me conciseness means fewer operations