# call a def within a block

Tags: scala

If there is any way to call a def  from a block

```
def factor (n: Int) : Int = if (n == 0 ) 1 else  n * factor(n-1)

val i = 1000

i.toString.foreach ( x => sum += factor(x.toInt) )
```

at the end I want to get the sum of factorial of every digit

But it seems like def  doesn't return a value, everytime is 0

How to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem actually has nothing to do with Scala per se; your code and your `def` are fine. The issue is with `toInt`:

```
scala> '3'.toInt
res7: Int = 51
```

`toInt` doesn't actually convert it as a decimal digit, but as a unicode (ish?) character value. These are producing very large numbers which go beyond what `factor` can handle:

```
scala> factor(6)
res8: Int = 720

scala> factor(20)
res9: Int = -2102132736

scala> factor(100)
res10: Int = 0
```

So instead use (thanks to Luigi)

```
x.asDigit
```

Comment: @Rogach Yes, I agree. I'll change it.

Comment: @Lguigi Why would `x.asDigit` be slower than `x - '0'`? Is it because it checks to make sure it's a digit?

Comment: Don't know, but there are some benchmarks I did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238353/scala-int-value-of-string-characters

Comment: `'3'.asDigit` uses implicit conversion and is equivalent to `Predef.charWrapper('3').asDigit`