# Scala - What type are the numbers in the List using x.toString.toList?

Tags: scala

I have written a function in Scala that should calculate the sum of the squares of the digits of a number. Eg: 44 -> 32 (4^2 + 4^2 = 16 + 16 = 32)

Here it is:

```
def digitSum(x:BigInt) : BigInt = {
    var sum = 0
    val leng = x.toString.toList.length
    var y = x.toString.toList
    for (i<-0 until leng ) {
      sum += y(i).toInt * y(i).toInt
    }
    return sum
  }
```

However when I call the function let's say with digitSum(44) instead of 32 I get 5408.

Why is this happening? Does it have to do with the fact that in the list there are Strings? If so why does the .toInt method do not work?

Thanks!

Comment: Oneliner: `BigInt(44).toString.map(_.asDigit).map(i => i*i).sum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your questions has been already covered here [Scala int value of String characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238353/scala-int-value-of-string-characters), have a good read through and you will have more information than required ;)

Also looking at your code, it can benefit more from Scala expressiveness and functional features. The same function can be written in the following manner:

```
  def digitSum(x: BigInt) = x.toString
    .map(_.asDigit)
    .map(a => a * a)
    .sum
```

In the future try to avoid using mutable variables and standard looping techniques if you could.

Comment: Yeah... It is not more than two weeks since I started so I am not so 'fluent' with Scala if I could use this expression.

Comment: Sure, and Stack Overflow community is here to help :) Good luck in exploring the functional world!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `toString` you're mapping the `String` to `Char`s not `Int`s and then to `Int`s later. This is what it looks like in the repl:

```
scala> "1".toList.map(_.toInt)
res0: List[Int] = List(49)
```

What you want is probably something like this:

```
def digitSum(x:BigInt) : BigInt = {
    var sum = 0
    val leng = x.toString.toList.length
    var y = x.toString.toList
    for (i<-0 until leng ) {
      sum += (y(i).toInt - 48) * (y(i).toInt - 48) //Subtract out char base
    }
   sum
  }
```

Comment: So this char base is standard?

Comment: @DoomProg this is how strings are represented `Char(49) = '1'`